# error with an angularjs filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Based on this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/

i add the filter solution for my app : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/popup.html#/ratousearch (ctrl : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/js/controllers/RatousearchCtrl.js )

```
//We already have a limitTo filter built-in to angular,
//let's make a startFrom filter
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Look console, error is getting at the started :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/js/baseChrome.js:368:22
    at http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/libs/angularjs/angular-1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js:180:297
    at B.| (http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/libs/angularjs/angular-1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js:169:248)
    at B.constant (http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/libs/angularjs/angular-1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js:179:161)
    at B.| (http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/libs/angularjs/angular-1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js:169:253)
    at B.constant (http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/libs/angularjs/angular-1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js:179:161)
    at Object.c (http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/libs/angularjs/angular-1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js:101:146)
    at m.$digest (http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/libs/angularjs/angular-1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js:114:386)
    at m.$apply (http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/libs/angularjs/angular-1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js:118:12)
    at k (http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/libs/angularjs/angular-1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js:76:374)
```

The line is

```
return input.slice(start);
```

what's wrong ? i didn't see error in the jsfiddle example

---

HTML :

```
        <div id="results" ng-show="successLordZR">
            <p class="myTitle">{{ 'TRS_CTRL3_TEXT1' | translate }} :</p>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="post in posts | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
                    <div class="myClearfix">
                    <p style="float: left;"><span ng-class="{'girl' : post.sex == 'F', 'boy' : post.sex == 'M'}">#</span>&nbsp; {{post.prefixe}} {{post.name}} ({{post.idLord}})</p>
                    <p style="float: right;"><a href="http://lord-rat.org/rats/rat_details.php?id={{post.id}}" title="lien lord" ng-click="createTab('http://lord-rat.org/rats/rat_details.php?id=' + post.id, $event);"><i class="fa fa-link"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;fiche</a></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="pagination">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ 'TRS_CTRL3_PREV' | translate }}&nbsp;</button>
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-disabled="currentPage >= posts.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">&nbsp;{{ 'TRS_CTRL3_NEXT' | translate }}&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Data json example from laravel : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/lordrest/public/posts_jsonforced

---

EDIT 2 , filter in controller:

```
            // populate scope
            $scope.posts = response;
            $scope.posts = $filter('startFrom')($scope.currentPage*$scope.pageSize);
```

filter is here : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/js/filtersZR.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the *posts* model in scope comes from *RatousearchCtrl*? In that controller the scope.posts was initially set to be an empty object and never updated.

That seems to be the reason why *post* as in ng-repeat 'post in posts' is undefined, which is the value got passed to the *startFrom* filter.

Can you re-check how *posts* are supposed to be loaded?

Comment: You're right, i have the error where is no data to populate posts, i update posts data with var myQuery = newData.query(); Is there a tip for telling filter be quiet where is no data or there is a mistake of my current code ?

Comment: I edited my question with new code, i try to use filter directly in controller, for control it. you can try "ar" in search input for see error is always here via console

Comment: @JoDiii For the first question: I would add code checking for invalid input before processing when there is no data; and I would use unit test to minimize the latter. For the second question, you will need to pass input value to the filter function in controller, try changing the line to `$scope.posts = $filter('startFrom')($scope.posts, $scope.currentPage*$scope.pageSize);`

Answer (score 1):

Input might not exist at that exact moment, just change your code to this:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return (typeof input == 'string') ? input.slice(start) : "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Try my edit, i'm not sure what input is at that time, but you might have to check if it's a string.

Comment: There is no more error but my data is not displayed :/

Comment: Then your input is empty, please provide the rest of your html, along with how you're getting the input.

Comment: If you remove the startFrom filter, does data show up?